# jQuery plugin, binding events only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, bind

I am building a lightbox jQuery plugin and I run into the problem, that the Events trigger as often, as I have lightboxes on the same page. Maybe you know, how to prevent this. Here is a sample Code.

```
;( function( $, window, document, undefined ){
'use strict';

$.fn.myPlugin = function( options ){

    // here are some functions for click and touching   
    $(document).on('click', '.elem', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('click');
    });

    $( document ).on( 'touchstart','.elem', function(e){
        console.log('touch');
    });

    return this;
};
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

So if I now call my plugin as often as I want to use it like:

```
$('.elem1').myPlugin();
...
$('.elem4').myPlugin();
```

The click or touch console.log will fire as often as I call the plugin. Do you have suggestion on how fix it?

Here is the current plugin in action with 4 Gallerys on one page.
http://andreknieriem.de/simple-lightbox-dev/

Comment: Use a boolean flag with an if maybe?

Comment: Tried it already, but it didn't work. Do you have a sample code?

Comment: Check if this is useful for you https://jsfiddle.net/6zn793cw/

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick calls the function for every element with the class of `.elem`. Also you are listening for a click anywhere on the page when you do `$(document).on('click'...`.  I'm guessing that's not what you're intended behavior is?  Do you mean `$(this).on('click' ...`?

Try something like:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function( options ){
    var target = this;

    // here are some functions for click and touching   
    $(document).on('click', target, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('click');
    });

    ...
```

Comment: Hi, no sorry, my Lightbox creates some Markup with the Big Image inside. this image should be dragable and the next, prev, close buttons clickable. You can see what is happening here:

http://andreknieriem.de/simple-lightbox-dev/